# Tester account locations and HowTo?

Tags: objective-c

When testing apps... is there a way to upload them to a location (and where) that can be down-loaded by testers to give me feedback on program flow and execution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about iOS apps... I highly recommend using [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/), it's worked really well in my experience.